When taking pictures with the front camera in SwiftUI, it is a mirror image
Picture before taking photo,hand on the right.

Picture after taking photo,hand on the left.

Here is the code
struct CameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var isPresented

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.cameraDevice = .front
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return imagePicker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
        
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(picker: self)
    }
}

It is expected that the previewed picture will be consistent with the taken picture.
